# Como pegar o item selecionado

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Olá, gostaria de uma ajuda,

Estou usando o framework da DEVEXPRESS.
Tenho um formulário com uma GridControl,
nesse GridControl tenho um evento DoubleClick.
Quando eu der um click na linha selecionada quero pega apenas apenas o ID
da linha. Usando um grid normal eu faço esse código para conseguir:

```
private void gvDados_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                this.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(gvDados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Nesse código eu consigo pegar o ID da linha que cliquei, mas quando uso o componente da DEVEXPRESSS GridControl, não tem o evendo CellDoubleClick, só o 
evento DoubleClick. Já tentei varias coisas, mas sem exito de pegar o ID da linha selecionada.

Se alguém ajuda, agradeço

Comment: tem que ser com double click? Se não me engano, o o grid control do dev não aceita double click nas rows

Comment: não tem uma função chamada GetFocusedRow() ? Geralmente ela retorna o objeto que está na linha.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, utilize o seguinte codigo para obter o valor da grelha na linha selecionada:

```
 gvDados.gettext(colunaID,grelha.activerow)
```

A coluna do id é sempre a mesma, a linha é a linha activa no momento.

Na sua linha têm de colocar a coluna correta que não pode ser 0. Mas sim a definida para id. Se for a `1a` da grelha é 1:

```
this.codigo = Convert.ToInt32(gvDados.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
```

Comment: Boa noite Daniel, eu estou usando o seguinte evento
 `private void gvDados_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }`
Devido o GridControl da DevExpress não ter o evento CellDoubleClick, logo eu não consigo usar o seguinte código que mencionei em cima.

Comment: Veja se o seguinte código ajuda:

private void gvDados_DoubleClick(Object eventSender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
      int Index = Array.IndexOf(this.gvDados,eventSender);
      
      if (Index  >= 0)
      { 
               gvDados.GetText(ColunaID, Grelha.ActiveRow);

      }
}

Testei com a grelha da devExpress no VS

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Utilizando o evento "DoubleClick" do DevExpress seria quase a mesma coisa.

```
private void grdView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = grdView1.GetFocusedDataSourceRowIndex();
    }
```